# Java Socket programming in cmd

Tags: java, windows, sockets, cmd

So I have the following code that runs on the telnet login in linux. How to make this run in cmd? I tried running the tcp client and server programs in cmd but I am not getting the output.
Here is my code that runs on linux telnet but not on windows cmd.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
class tcpclient{
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    String hwaddr,modsentence;
    BufferedReader inFromUser=new BufferedReader(new      InputStreamReader(System.in));
    Socket clientSocket=new Socket("localhost",2057);
    DataOutputStream outToServer= new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader inFromServer=new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream())); 
    System.out.print("Enter Ip address");
    hwaddr=inFromUser.readLine();
    outToServer.writeBytes(hwaddr+""+"\n");
    modsentence=inFromServer.readLine();
    System.out.println("FROM SERVER:"+modsentence);
    clientSocket.close();
}
}
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
class tcpserver{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        String clientSentence;
        ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(2057);
        while(true)
        {
            Socket connectionSocket=welcomeSocket.accept();
            BufferedReader inFromClient=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connectionSocket.getInputStream()));
            DataOutputStream outToClient=new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            clientSentence=inFromClient.readLine();
            if(clientSentence.equals("a"))
                outToClient.writeBytes("testtt");

       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Please edit your code so that it's correctly indented.

Comment: How do you run it in linux?

Comment: And make sure it actually works. there's not \n in your response. So that's not a line.

Comment: Or just remove the client, as this is about telnet.

Comment: One thing I notice in tcpclient is that it connects to localhost directly. The user of tcpclient can't decide which IP address to connect to although the user is told to enter an IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
outToClient.writeBytes("testtt");
```

to

```
outToClient.writeBytes("testtt\n");
```

According to https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine()

> readLine()  Reads a line of text. A line is considered to be terminated by any one of a **line feed ('\n')**, a carriage return ('\r'), or a carriage return followed immediately by a linefeed.

This would make

```
modsentence = inFromServer.readLine();
```

return a String and assign it to modsentence.

Also remember that your tcpserver only responds to character "a".

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: It's not relevant whether you use bash or CMD. Socket programming is the same because the shell doesn't interfere. You send some characters to the server and the servers sends some characters back. I have tested this in CMD and it works the same.

Comment: Yes, a \n was missing. there was an error in the code. Thanks for your feedback anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) then you should also use a [BufferedWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html).
Also note `DataInputStream.readLine()` is deprecated and should not be used.
With all that being said, yes there is a difference between the Command Prompt in Windows, and the Shell in Linux. Windows uses **\r\n** as a line terminator, and Linux uses **\n**. If you use **\r\n** as a line feed, it should work fine on all platforms. However you never will realistically use the Command Prompt in a real client/server architecture so it's best not to base your application off of windows ancient features. use **\n**.

Try using [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to get input from **System.in**